# Fetching data from API in django

Tags: python, django, api

I have access to an outside API which have some data something like the following:

```
{
   "Successful":true,
   "Message":"[{\"Id\":1,\"GroupId\":0,\"QuestionTitle\":\"What is your first name?\",\"GroupName\":null,\"QuestionType\":\"TEXT\",\"IsMappingAvailable\":null,\"BodyRegion\":0,\"EnableCalculation\":false,\"Responses\":[]},{\"Id\":2,\"GroupId\":0,\"QuestionTitle\":\"And your last name?\",\"GroupName\":null,\"QuestionType\":\"TEXT\",\"IsMappingAvailable\":null,\"BodyRegion\":0,\"EnableCalculation\":false,\"Responses\":[]}]"
}
```

Now I want to show all these `Id` and `QuestionTitle` in my template.

my `views.py`:

```
def GetQuestion(request):
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXX='}
    body = { "Tenant" : "devED" }
    GetQuestion_response = requests.post('https://url_name.com/api/GetQuestions', headers=headers, json=body).json()
    GetQuestion_dict={
        'GetQuestion_response' : GetQuestion_response,
    }
    return render(request, 'app\GetQuestion.html', GetQuestion_dict)
```

in my `template`:

```
{% for i in GetQuestion_response.Message %}
      <h2>ID: {{ i.Id }}</h2>
      <h2>QuestionTitle: {{ i.QuestionTitle }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

But unfortunately, it shows no results. Maybe it's because the value of the `Message` key in the API is inside the **double quote** (like a string).

**Please suggest how can I fix this**?

Comment: what do you get if you add `{{ GetQuestion_response }}` to the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case since `Message` is returned as a string, it needs to be parsed again as json like this:

```
import json

def GetQuestion(request):
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXX='}
    body = { "Tenant" : "devED" }
    GetQuestion_response = requests.post('https://url_name.com/api/GetQuestions', headers=headers, json=body).json()
    
    # Parse message as json
    GetQuestion_response = json.loads(GetQuestion_response['Message'])
    
    GetQuestion_dict={
        'GetQuestion_response' : GetQuestion_response,
    }
    return render(request, 'app\GetQuestion.html', GetQuestion_dict)
```

And then in the template, just use `GetQuestion_response`:

```
{% for i in GetQuestion_response %}
    <h2>ID: {{ i.Id }}</h2>
    <h2>QuestionTitle: {{ i.QuestionTitle }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```